# GLSL maximum number of instructions

Tags: glsl

Is there a maximum number of assembly language instructions to be loaded into the fragment program unit?
I have an algorithm on to port from cpu to gpu and apparently it doesn't fit on the gpu.

Comment: I know nothing about shaders, but I'd guess that they don't have infinite storage space.

Answer (score 43):

There are several hard and soft limits, some of which are not immediately obvious:

- Instruction slots: The total number of instructions that the hardware can accomodate in local memory.
- Executed instructions: The maximum number of instructions that will execute (including instructions that run several times in a loop)
- A single GLSL instruction can map to a dozen or more instructions
- Several GLSL instructions can map to a single instruction depending on the optimizer's quality (e.g. multiply-add, dot, lerp)
- Limited temp registers (only 32) may require more instructions than necessary on pre-SM4 hardware (no such problem with 4096).
- Swizzling usually does not cost extra instructions nowadays, but *does* on some older hardware, and *may in some situations* on some hardware (esp. gl_FragColor is such a candidate)
- Regardless of actual instructions, OpenGL 2.0 compatible hardware is limited to 8 dependent texture fetches (unlimited on hardware that can do OpenGL 2.1 or better)

You have these guaranteed minimums (most cards have more):

- 512 instruction slots for vertex and pixel shaders on OpenGL 2.x (SM3) capable hardware

  - 65536 executed instructions
- 4096 vertex and 65536 pixel shader instruction slots on 3.x (SM4) hardware

  - 65536 executed vertex shader instructions, unlimited pixel shader instructions
- At least 24 dynamic branches possible on 2.x (SM3) hardware
- Fully dynamic branching (no limits) on SM4 hardware
- Only conditional move available on SM2.x, everything else must be accomodated by code duplication and loop unrolling, or must fail

Comment: This is a great answer, however it'd be better with some references.

Answer (score 2):

There is a limit on the maximum amount of instructions a shader can have. As far as I know, it varies from GPU to GPU. If your shader is too large, compilation will generate an error.